# Layering with shadow in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement this design:

[image]

There is a scrollabe column that contains items underneath the buttons when there is no enough space.

I tried to do this:

```
  Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                SubtitleSelector(
                    state.selectedSubtitle
                ) { vm.setSubtitle(it) }


                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(Theme.spacing.small_3)
                ) {
                    ClearAllButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                        vm.clearAll()
                    }

                    ApplyButton(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {

                    }
                }
            }
```

But the items disappear when they go underneath the buttons, I want them to appear with a little shadow like the image above.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you can wrap all the content in a Box(). Inside Box(), let the list go to the bottom, then a Row() containing 2 Button(), set the background for Row().

In my example, I use **Brush.verticalGradient()** to set a gradient background that creates a smooth gradation of the container. Or you can set the background color to an alpha color that also has the same blur effect. But surely gradients would be better:

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val list = listOf(
        "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff",
        "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm",
        "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt"
    )
    val heightForButton = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp * 0.3
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(12.dp)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            content = {
                items(list) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 8.dp)
                            .background(
                                color = Color.DarkGray,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                            )
                            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
                        text = it,
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                    )
                }
            }
        )

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(heightForButton.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color(0xE6FFFFFF))
                    )
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .border(
                        width = 1.dp,
                        color = Color.Red,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )
                    .background(
                        color = Color.White,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(8.dp),
                text = "Cancel",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(8.dp),
                text = "Accept",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]